# What is this error and how to fix it?: ValueError: Invalid value supplied 'WktVersion.WKT2_2019'

Tags: python, geopandas, wkt

I am trying to read a .shx file into my Python script using geopandas and I receive:

"ValueError: Invalid value supplied 'WktVersion.WKT2_2019'. Only ('WKT2_2015', 'WKT2_2015_SIMPLIFIED', 'WKT2_2018', 'WKT2_2018_SIMPLIFIED', 'WKT2_2019', 'WKT2_2019_SIMPLIFIED', 'WKT1_GDAL', 'WKT1_ESRI') are supported.".

I am reading in other .shx files into my script and they work fine, but not with this one particular file.

I tried to read about Well Known Text (WKT) but I do not understand how to "supply" the the supported WKT value.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The file you have was written by a modern suite of libraries,
but you're trying to use downrev libraries to read it.

The geopandas [install docs](https://geopandas.org/en/latest/getting_started/install.html#creating-a-new-environment)
offer advice on how to re-install libraries
into a fresh environment.
Prefer to use `conda` for everything,
rather than bringing in some deps from condaforge
and some via `pip install`.